# data type (int vs float) with sklearn models

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I have a rather general question.
I am trying to create a classification model and my training data consists of various variables. I have figured out that it would be most efficient if I convert all my data into numeric types. However, as I am using 2D numpy array and I have to use float for values that are originally stored as integers. I wanted to ask if having such conversion would effect the efficiency of my prediction,
or simply:
Is there a difference between having 1.00-0.00's and 1-0's in a training set.

Comment: Numpy arrays can have [mixed types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832715/numpy-array-matrix-of-mixed-types).

Comment: thank you for your answer.
except for 1 column, everything is converted to float, and I have around 240 columns. that's why I was looking for a rather general answer